# What's the proper syntax for the Terminal MV command when you want to move a folder's contents, or is there a better approach?

Tags: terminal

For testing purposes I have two folders in my User folder: Source and Dest

There's a file in the Source folder that I want to move to Dest, and delete Source in the process.

`mv ~/Source ~/Dest` moves the Source folder and its contents into Dest. I don't want Source to be subfolder in Dest; I want it gone.

`mv ~/Source/ ~/Dest` yields the same results, which surprised me because I thought adding / to the end of ~/Source/ would cause its contents to move independent of the source folder.

`mv ~/Source/* ~/Dest` does what I want but I read somewhere that some files (.file ?) wouldn't be copied.

Plus, I don't want to change the file timestamps, ownership, attributes and whatever other hidden stuff exists beyond my paygrade.

I'm starting to think I should use a two-line script instead, to ensure that the copy is exact:

```
ditto ~/source ~/dest
sudo rm -rf ~/source
```

Am I overlooking anything here? Is the 2-line script the best one?

Comment: Use rename command to rename Source to Dest. Also avoid sudo if not required on this folder.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? *mv* in the same directory basically just changes the name (see comment above, use *rename*). Do you want to move the folder to a different dir while changing it's name? This works fine here.

Comment: The destination folder in actual use will be on another drive. I used simple paths here for convenience in reproducing the examples.  My primary goal with this question is to verify whether adding / after the source path should make a difference in the results. I've seen examples and experienced other situations (probably not on a Mac) where adding adding the / changes the results from copying the folder and its contents to copying only the contents.